# Números em Ordem Crescente C

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um código para mostrar 3 números aleatórios em ordem crescente digitados pelo usuário entretanto não entendo o motivo do meu código não estar funcionando

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

int numeros[3],a,b,c,maior=0,menor=0,medio=0;



printf("Digite 3 numeros:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d",&numeros[0],&numeros[1],&numeros[2]);


for(a=0;a<3;a++){
    if(numeros[a]>numeros[a+1]){
        numeros[a]=maior;
    }


}
for(b=0;b<3;b++){
    if(numeros[b]<numeros[b+1]){
        numeros[b]=menor;
    }
}
for(c=0;c<3;c++){
    if(numeros[c]<maior && numeros[c]>menor){
        numeros[c]=medio;
    }
}

printf("%d %d %d",menor,medio,maior);
```

de output aparece apenas 0 em todas as 3 posições.

Comment: Se sua intenção é apenas colocar nas variaveis `maior`, `medio` e `menor`, creio que você inverteu. Você parece estar colocando no vetor o valor da variável maior, que não estava inicializada, na linha numeros[a]=maior. Experimente trocar para maior = numeros[a].

Comment: Continua sem funcionar mesmo assim

Comment: Se desejar, escrevi uma resposta para ordenar 8 números sem usar vetores nem laços. Dou também uma noção do porquê foi feito daquele jeito e alguma base teórica no assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240531/64969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está verificando erros?

Pois nos ifs irá dar erro por estourar o array em "[a+1]" e "[b+1]": `numeros[a]>numeros[a+1]` e `numeros[a]>numeros[b+1]`.

Você inverteu a atribuição de valor:

```
numeros[a]=maior;
numeros[b]=menor;
numeros[c]=medio;
```

Alterar para:

```
maior=numeros[a];
menor=numeros[b];
medio=numeros[c];
```

Você também pode fazer dessa forma:

```
int i, j, a, n, number[30];

printf("Enter the value of N \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter the numbers \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    scanf("%d", &number[i]);
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (number[i] > number[j])
        {
            a =  number[i];
            number[i] = number[j];
            number[j] = a;
        }
    }
}
printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", number[i]);
```

Fonte:
http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sort-array-ascending-order/

Comment: "Estranho" a gente ter downvote em uma pergunta aceita! haha

Comment: Creio que deixar claro que aqui se está rodando um `selection sort` seja positivo para um futuro leitor

Answer (score 5):

Este código é complexo demais, não precisa disto tudo e achei a resposta aceita ainda pior porque virou um algoritmo quadrático (não que faça muita diferença em caso tão simples), então aqui vai uma solução mais simples. Se quiser usar *array* mesmo, que é desnecessário, é só trocar as variáveis. Se quer fazer um *loop* dá também, mas fica mais complicado e por isso não tem sentido.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Digite 3 numeros:\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a > c) {
        int tmp = c;
        c = a;
        a = tmp;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a;
        a = tmp;
    }
    if (b > c) {
        int tmp = c;
        c = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BLizoZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ftjydfpu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SortThree.c).

Dá para generalizar uma função de *swap* para evitar essas 3 linhas de troca, mas em um exemplo simples assim nem compensa.

Sempre prefiro usar a [Navalha de Occam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Answer (score 0):

Que tal uma coisa mais simples, não é algo tão flexível com uma quantidade maior de números, mas com apenas 3 fica bem fácil de entender. Usa um pouco de analise combinatória, são 3 espaços para três números distintos (3 x 2 x 1 = 6), então são apenas 6 possíveis formas diferentes de posicionar as 3 variáveis com os possíveis números

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int num1, num2, num3;
    printf("digite tres valores (separe os numeros com um espaco): ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    if (num1 > num2 and num2 > num3)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num3, num2, num1);
        
    if (num3 > num2 and num2 > num1)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num1, num2, num3);
        
    if (num2 > num1 and num1 > num3)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num3, num1, num2);
        
    if (num1 > num3 and num3 > num2)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num1, num3, num2);
        
    if (num2 > num3 and num3 > num1)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num1, num3, num2);
        
    if (num3 > num1 and num1 > num2)
        printf ("%d, %d, %d", num2, num1, num3);
}
```