# VisualG - 5 números maiores

Tags: classificação, visualg

Eu estou recebendo 5 valores e preciso ordernar do menor ao maior, sem usar loop ou array.

Eu consegui apenas descobrir o menor e o maior; como poderia descobrir os do meio? Segue o que fiz até agora:

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
// Disciplina  :  [Linguagem e Lógica de Programação] 
// Professor   : Antonio Carlos Nicolodi 
// Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
// Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
// Data atual  : 25/09/2017
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 : inteiro
maior, menor : inteiro
Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 


escreval("Numero 1:")
leia(n1)

escreval("Numero 2:")
leia(n2)

escreval("Numero 3:")
leia(n3)

escreval("Numero 4:")
leia(n4)

escreval("Numero 5:")
leia(n5)

se (n1 > n2) e (n1 > n3) e (n1 > n4) e (n1 > n5) entao
      maior <- n1
fimse

se (n2 > n1) e (n2 > n3) e (n2 > n4) e (n2 > n5) entao
      maior <- n2
fimse

se (n3 > n1) e (n3 > n2) e (n3 > n4) e (n3 > n5) entao
      maior <- n3
fimse

se (n4 > n1) e (n4 > n2) e (n4 > n3) e (n4 > n5) entao
      maior <- n4
fimse

se (n5 > n1) e (n5 > n2) e (n5 > n3) e (n5 > n4) entao
      maior <- n5
fimse

se (n1 < n2) e (n1 < n3) e (n1 < n4) e (n1 < n5) entao
      menor <- n1
fimse

se (n2 < n1) e (n2 < n3) e (n2 < n4) e (n2 < n5) entao
      menor <- n2
fimse

se (n3 < n1) e (n3 < n2) e (n3 < n4) e (n3 < n5) entao
      menor <- n3
fimse

se (n4 < n1) e (n4 < n2) e (n4 < n3) e (n4 < n5) entao
      menor <- n4
fimse

se (n5 < n1) e (n5 < n2) e (n5 < n3) e (n5 < n4) entao
      menor <- n5
fimse

escreval(menor)

escreval(maior)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Defina "do meio".

Comment: @Maniero O terceiro.

Answer (score 3):

Sua redação está ruim. Não deixou claro qual o resultado esperado, nem tampouco qual era sua dúvida.

Creio que você está se perguntando como fazer para ordenar as variáveis `n1` até `n5` para imprimi-las. Correto? Pois bem, esse é um ótimo caso para estudar redes de ordenação.

A explicação mais detalhada está [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214190/64969). Vou transcrever os trechos mais relevantes:

> Uma rede de ordenação é composta por **fios horizontais** que representam as posições no array, e também por **pontes verticais** que ligam fios. Toda ponte conecta única e exclusivamente dois fios; em cada ponte, os elementos dos dois fios conectados são comparados e, caso seja necessário, trocados. Também tem outra propriedade interessante em redes de ordenação: o tempo passa da esquerda para a direita, e um fio só pode estar em uma ponte ao mesmo tempo.
>
> [image: rede de ordenação para 8 fios]

No seu caso, cada posição é definida por uma variável, não por uma posição do vetor.

Você pode pesquisar qual a rede de ordenação mais otimizada para cinco posições, eu vou por aqui o pseudocódigo para 8 variáveis. Note também que já considero que `n0` a `n7` já vem com os valores preenchidos de algum lugar. Note também que uso indexação posicional estilo [c](/questions/tagged/c), por isso começo em 0.

```
se n0 > n1:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n1
    n1 = swp
se n2 > n3:
    swp = n2
    n2 = n3
    n3 = swp
se n4 > n5:
    swp = n4
    n4 = n5
    n5 = swp
se n6 > n7:
    swp = n6
    n6 = n7
    n7 = swp
# fim do primeiro bloco

se n0 > n3:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n3
    n3 = swp
se n1 > n2:
    swp = n1
    n1 = n2
    n3 = swp
se n4 > n7:
    swp = n4
    n4 = n7
    n7 = swp
se n5 > n6:
    swp = n5
    n5 = n6
    n6 = swp
# fim do segundo bloco

se n0 > n1:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n1
    n1 = swp
se n2 > n3:
    swp = n2
    n2 = n3
    n3 = swp
se n4 > n5:
    swp = n4
    n4 = n5
    n5 = swp
se n6 > n7:
    swp = n6
    n6 = n7
    n7 = swp
# fim do terceiro bloco

se n0 > n7:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n7
    n7 = swp
se n1 > n6:
    swp = n1
    n1 = n6
    n6 = swp
se n2 > n5:
    swp = n2
    n2 = n5
    n5 = swp
se n3 > n4:
    swp = n3
    n3 = n4
    n4 = swp
# fim do quarto bloco

se n0 > n2:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n2
    n2 = swp
se n1 > n3:
    swp = n1
    n1 = n3
    n3 = swp
se n4 > n6:
    swp = n4
    n4 = n6
    n6 = swp
se n5 > n7:
    swp = n5
    n5 = n7
    n7 = swp
# fim do quinto bloco

se n0 > n1:
    swp = n0
    n0 = n1
    n1 = swp
se n2 > n3:
    swp = n2
    n2 = n3
    n3 = swp
se n4 > n5:
    swp = n4
    n4 = n5
    n5 = swp
se n6 > n7:
    swp = n6
    n6 = n7
    n7 = swp
```

Ao final da execução, garanto que:

```
n0 <= n1 <= n2 <= n3 <= n4 <= n5 <= n6 <= n7
```

Essa rede de ordenação em específico eu utilizei do bitonic-merge-sort mais otimizado possível para uso de paralelismo. Talvez seja o caso de você procurar outra rede de ordenação, como rede para bubble-sort ou rede para selection-sort.