# (Python) Ordenar listas sem o sort()

Tags: python, classificação

como ordenar uma lista sem usar o sort()? O codigo abaixo está correto, porém o professor não quer que use o sort(). O codigo tem a seguinte instrução: " Faça um programa que, no momento de preencher uma lista com 8 números inteiros, já os armazene de forma crescente. Mostre a lista resultante cada vez que um valor for armazenado."

```
lista = []
for x in range(8):
    n = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
    lista.append(n)
    lista.sort()

    print(lista)
```

Comment: Já estudou sobre algoritmos de ordenação?

Comment: Sem usar listas, vetores ou `sort`, ordenando 8 números: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240531/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado essa pergunta compartilhada não é igual e a resposta adjunta também não responde exatamente a pergunta do Van Sheur. O algoritmo pedido é um que vá ordenando conforme cada entrada vai chegando. O compartilhado por você ordena depois que todos os dados estão presentes. Além disso, na compartilhada é pedido que não se use comandos de laço, tornando o código desnecessariamente gigante - o que não se aplica aqui.

Comment: @José por não ser igual não sugeri duplicata ;-)

Comment: Pessoas,e eu só acho que quando for uma pergunta desse tipo dá pra rsponder dando umas dicas de como começar,  _sem_ precisar fazer o exercício inteiro né?? #xatiado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução um pouco mais [*pythonica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878) da [resposta do José](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252403/5878) seria:

```
numeros = []
for _ in range(8):
    numero = int(input("Digite um número: "))
    for chave, valor in enumerate(numeros):
        if numero < valor:
            numeros.insert(chave, numero)
            break
    else:
        numeros.append(numero)
    print("Lista atual:", numeros)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XNjjEn) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Njrv/1)</sup>

Utilizando a estrutura do `else` do `for` pode-se excluir a ideia da *flag*, simplificando o código.

Vale ressaltar que, no pior caso, este algoritmo irá fazer N comparações, sendo N o tamanho atual da lista. Para 8 números isso não é crítico, mas a medida que essa quantia aumentar, poderia se tornar um gargalo no desempenho. Como possivelmente é apenas um exercício para fixar as estruturas de repetição e controle, acredito que não precisa se preocupar com isso agora, mas se for de interesse, estude outros algoritmos de ordenação e tente implementá-los da mesma forma.

Isso ainda inclui a pergunta [citada pelo Jefferson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252400/python-ordenar-listas-sem-o-sort/252405#comment517821_252400), onde você pode tentar adaptar para 8 números:

[VisualG - 5 números maiores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240439/5878)

Answer (score 1):

## Vejamos...

### Você precisa de:

- receber valores para ordenar em uma lista
- tal ordenação precisa ser feita conforme recebe tais valores
- não pode usar o método `.sort(...)`

### Informações úteis para solucionar o problema

Você deve utilizar recursos que lidem com posicionamento de um dado na lista na hora de fazer a inserção. Neste caso, o método `.insert(index, valor)`.

Este método, ao inserir na posição dada, empurra para a direita o valor que previamente havia lá. Exemplo:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.insert(2, 'oi!')
```

Ao inserir `'oi'` na posição 2 da lista `a`, obtemos a seguinte configuração para `a`:

```
[1,2,'oi',3,4,5]
```

Para efetivamente criar a lista de forma ordenada sem o método `.sort(...)`, você também vai precisar fazer laço (*loop*) aninhado. Também pode vir a precisar de uma variável de marcação - uma *flag*, como chamamos na área.

### Exemplo de como poderia ficar o código:

```
lista = []
flag = False

for x in range(8):

    tamanho = len(lista)

    n = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

    if( tamanho > 0 ):

        for y in range( tamanho ):

            if ( n <= lista[y] ):

                lista.insert( y, n )

                flag = True

                break

    if((x == 0) or (flag == False)):

        lista.append( n )

    else:

        flag = False

print(lista)
```

### Considerações finais

Recomendo que pesquise sobre o tema ([algoritmos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) e que tente quebrar a cabeça antes de copiar pura e simplesmente o código acima. Ao aprender, sempre é bom que tente muito - mas tente muito *mesmo* - resolver os exercícios/deveres/desafios/etc sozinho para então conseguir aprender a ser autodidata e a se acostumar a um modo novo de raciocínio que virá mais rapidamente depois de um tempo. Vai ampliar bem seus horizontes e aguçar sua mente e te preparar para um momento em que não vai haver professor nem solução pronta!