# Ordenar listas sem o sort

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando resolver um exercício porém estou sem resultado algum por enquanto.
Sou novato na linguagem.

'''Defina uma função merge que faz o seguinte:
Dadas duas listas ordenadas L1 e L2,
retorna uma lista ordenada com todos os números de L1 e L2.

A função NAO deve usar o método sort do python.

Em vez disso, faça o seguinte:
* Crie um indice i1 para a lista L1 e um i2 para L2
* Inicialize i1 e i2 com 0
* Compare L1[i1] com L2[i2] e coloque o menor dos dois
na lista de resposta. Se o menor era L1[i1], aumente i1.
Caso contrário, aumente i2
* Assim, L1[i1] e L2[i2] são sempre os menores elementos
de L1 e L2, e um deles é sempre o proximo que deve entrar
na resposta
* Continue fazendo isso até adicionar todos os elementos
de L1 e L2 na resposta'''

Tentei fazer algo do tipo abaixo

```
def merge(lista1, lista2):
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    resposta = []
    lista = lista1 + lista2
    for num in lista:
        if num < lista2[i2]:
            resposta.append(lista1[i1])
            i1 += 1
        else:
            resposta.append(lista2[i2])
            i2 += 1
    return resposta
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252400/python-ordenar-listas-sem-o-sort
Vê se isto ajuda...

Comment: O nome disso é balance line, juntar duas listas já ordenadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome desse algoritmo é 'Balance Line', era algo costumeiramente implementado nos tempos do COBOL, onde os dados vinham ordenados de fitas magnéticas, creio eu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def merge(lista1, lista2):
        i1 = 0
        i2 = 0
        resposta = []
        while True:
                if i1 < len(lista1) and i2 < len(lista2):
                        if lista1[i1] <= lista2[i2]:
                                resposta.append(lista1[i1])
                                i1 += 1
                        else:
                                resposta.append(lista2[i2])
                                i2 += 1
                elif i1 < len(lista1):
                        # lista2 esgotada
                        resposta.append(lista1[i1])
                        i1 += 1
                elif i2 < len(lista2):
                        # lista1 esgotada
                        resposta.append(lista2[i2])
                        i2 += 1
                else:
                        # Ambas listas esgotadas
                        break
        return resposta

print(merge([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!